# Filter rows with dplyr/magrittr based on entire row

Tags: r, dplyr

One is able to filter rows with dplyr with `filter`, but the condition is usually based on specific columns per row such as

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,NA),y=c(3,NA,NA),z=c(NA,4,5))
d %>% filter(!is.na(y))
```

I want to filter the row by whether the number of NA is greater than 50%, such as

```
d %>% filter(mean(is.na(EACHROW)) < 0.5 )
```

How do I do this in a dplyr/magrittr flow fashion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `rowSums` or `rowMeans` for that. An example with the provided data:

```
> d
   x  y  z
1  1  3 NA
2  2 NA  4
3 NA NA  5

# with rowSums:
d %>% filter(rowSums(is.na(.))/ncol(.) < 0.5)

# with rowMeans:
d %>% filter(rowMeans(is.na(.)) < 0.5)
```

which both give:

```
  x  y  z
1 1  3 NA
2 2 NA  4
```

As you can see row 3 is removed from the data.

---

In base R, you could just do:

```
d[rowMeans(is.na(d)) < 0.5,]
```

to get the same result.

Comment: Why is `d %>% filter(mean(is.na(.)) < 0.5)` not working then?

Comment: Answer: Because `.` is not the row, but the whole data.frame and mean can not deal with data.frames. So I have to write `d %>% filter(rowMeans(is.na(.)) < 0.5)`.

Comment: @Make42 that's basically the same as my answer ;-) i will add that to it