# rowwise filtering in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to use dplyr instead of `apply,1` in order to filter a dataset rowwise according to a logical expression, ie for this example I´d like to remove all rows that have one or more values of 99.
However, I was surprised by the poor performance in dplyr. Any ideas if I can speed this up in dplyr? Also, I would have thought that the rowwise function would pipe the individual rows, but apparently not (see below). How can I use the rowwise function?

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
s <- tibble(rows = seq(from = 250, to = 5000, by = 250)) #my original dataset has 400K rows...
s$num <- map(s$rows,  ~ rnorm(.x * 6))
s$num <-
  map(s$num,  ~ replace(.x, sample(1:length(.x), size = length(.x) / 20), 99))
s$mat <- map(s$num,  ~ as_data_frame(matrix(.x, ncol = 6)))

help_an <- function(vec) {
  browser()
  return(!any(vec == 99))
}

help_dp_t <- function(df) {
  clo1 <- proc.time()
  a <- as_data_frame(t(df)) %>% summarise_all(help_an)
  df2 <- filter(df, t(a)[, 1])
  b <- tibble(time = (proc.time() - clo1)[3], df = list(df2))
  return(b)
}

s$dplyr <- map(s$mat,  ~ dplyr::mutate(help_dp_t(.x)))

help_lap <- function(df) {
  clo1 <- proc.time()
  a_base <- df[apply(df, 1, function(x)
    ! any(x == 99)), ]
  b <- tibble(time = (proc.time() - clo1)[3], df = list(a_base))
  return(b)
}

s$lapply <- map(s$mat,  ~ mutate(help_lap(.x)))
s$equal_dplyr_lapply <-
  map2_lgl(s$dplyr, s$lapply,  ~ all.equal(.x$df, .y$df))

s$dplyr_time <- map_dbl(s$dplyr, "time")
s$lapply_time <- map_dbl(s$lapply, "time")

ggplot(gather(s, ... = c(7, 8)), aes(x = rows, y = value, color = key)) +
  geom_line()
```

I tried the following with rowwise, but the rowwise pipe does not send a vector, but the entire df to the help_an function.

```
help_dp_r <- function(df) {
      clo1 <- proc.time()
      df2 <-
        df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(cond = help_an(.)) ### . is not passed on as a vector, but the entire df??
      b <- tibble(time = (proc.time() - clo1)[3], df = list(df2))
    }

    s$dplyr_r <- map(s$mat,  ~ dplyr::mutate(help_dp_r(.x)))
```

Comment: I would be helpful if you explained in words what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @jaap See my edit. Quite general - I´d like to filter a dataframe according to a logical expression rowwise using dplyr.

Comment: What's the added value of nesting dataframes inside dataframes?

Comment: anyway, for a simple dataframe you could do something like: `df[rowSums(df == 99) == 0, ]`

Comment: @Jaap. I just like to keep all my data and edit in one df. But that is completely beside the point.

Comment: @jaap.That is hardly a dplyr solution, is it?  I can do it in many different ways in base-R, but I was surprised at the poor speed and scaling in dplyr which is usually quite fast and readable.

Comment: dplyr isn't the solution to everything; when base R works better, I would suggest to use just that

Comment: @jaap Admittedly. I guess there is no need to reinvent the wheel. The rowSums solutions was 4000 times faster than my dplyr version at 5000 rows.However, this makes me distrust my own dplyr filtering...

Comment: If you want it piped, just use @Jaap's suggestion within `filter` e.g. `df %>% filter(rowSums(. == 99) == 0)` detailed in a previous answer of his [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652150/filter-rows-with-dplyr-magrittr-in-r-based-on-entire-row).

Comment: Very good--does anyone use the Rowwise function at all? In case yes-how and when do you use it?