# How to remove rows with a specific percentage of the elements less than a number

Tags: r

I have a matrix with the first column made of characters and 16 columns of numbers. Something like this:

```
 V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
E.5    13    16    19     7
E.2     7     3     3     5
E.6     7     7     6     6
E.1    30    18    28    16
E.3    51    54    52    44
```

I want to filter rows that have more than X% of the elements (for example more than 75% of the elements) less than a specific number (let's say 10).

I have already a function like this:

```
filter <- function(m,n){
b <- sapply(1:length(m[,1]),function(x){all(m[x,2:length(m[1,])]<n)})   # to filter out rows of matrix "m" with all elements smaller than "n".
m[!b,]}
```

How can I change it to my requirements?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [*Filter rows with dplyr/magrittr based on entire row*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34652150/2204410)

Comment: Based on the link above: `df[rowMeans(df[,2:5] < 10) > 0.75, ]`

Comment: It seems not to be working the way I want. If my matrix is cmat, here is how I ran it:

t=cmat[rowMeans(cmat[,2:5] < 10) > 0.75, ]

Comment: I think that my question isn't a duplicate of that post.

Comment: Is it a matrix or a dataframe? If it is a matrix, you'd better converst it to a dataframe as a matrix can only have one class of of values. Because the first column is a character column, all values in the matrix will be converted to characters. Which might be the reason it is not working.

Comment: It's a matrix. it works but it seems to remove the rows I want and keep the rows I don't want.

Comment: Just alter the expression to `df[rowMeans(df[,2:5] > 10) > 0.75, ]` or `df[rowMeans(df[,2:5] < 10) < 0.75, ]`

Comment: Thank you. These two functions are not equivalent. And I want to remove those rows that have more than 75% of the elements less than 10. None of these functions do that.

Comment: @Uwe would you please take a look at this question? thank you

Comment: They are indeed not equivalent. Either `df[rowMeans(df[,2:5] < 10) < 0.75, ]` or `df[rowMeans(df[,2:5] > 10) >= 0.75, ]` removes the rows that have more than 75% of the elements less than 10.

Comment: Thank you Jaap. df is the name of my dataframe?

Comment: yes, you can replace it with whatever your dataframe is called

Comment: df[rowMeans(df[,2:5] < 10) < 0.75, ] works now. I don't know why it didn't work at first. Thank you very much.